# AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype' when creating a new dataframe based on two other dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to create a new dataframe `df_rest` based on two other dataframes `exon_rna` and `clin_kipan` by retaining the rows of `exon_rna` with indices unique from `clin_kipan`.

```
df_rest = pd.DataFrame(index=list( set( exon_rna.index.tolist()) - set( clin_kipan.index.tolist()) ), columns=clin_kipan.columns)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df_rest = pd.DataFrame(index=list( set( exon_rna.index.tolist()) - set( clin_kipan.index.tolist()) ), columns=clin_kipan.columns)
      2 df_rest

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:411, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    407     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    408         data, axes=dict(index=index, columns=columns), dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    409     )
    410 elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 411     mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    412 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    413     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:242, in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    240         else:
    241             nan_dtype = dtype
--> 242         val = construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(np.nan, len(index), nan_dtype)
    243         arrays.loc[missing] = [val] * missing.sum()
    245 else:

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py:1229, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(value, length, dtype)
   1227 else:
   1228     if not isinstance(dtype, (np.dtype, type(np.dtype))):
-> 1229         dtype = dtype.dtype
   1231     if length and is_integer_dtype(dtype) and isna(value):
   1232         # coerce if we have nan for an integer dtype
   1233         dtype = np.dtype("float64")

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Data:

`exon_rna.head()`

```
pd.DataFrame({'chr1:11874-12227:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.15591837759944',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.2719547'},
 'chr1:12595-12721:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.24834693214939',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7301587'},
 'chr1:12613-12721:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.289358352137362',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8518519'},
 'chr1:12646-12697:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.454904717062103',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8823529'},
 'chr1:13221-14409:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.954955570888991',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.6026936'},
 'chr1:13403-14409:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.02575668077691',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.6272366'},
 'chr1:14363-16765:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '13.7323296611257',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:16854-17055:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '33.8431093465806',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:17233-18061:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '24.0355043992073',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9106280'},
 'chr1:18268-18379:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '39.6362812402087',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:18497-18554:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '16.5857214082873',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:18913-19759:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '12.3069539038635',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:24738-24901:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '11.683284562595',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9570552'},
 'chr1:29321-29370:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.57700301914863',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:29824-29961:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.628515696037495',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:34612-35174:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0280107108196914',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1708185'},
 'chr1:35277-35481:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.115390464815753',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:35721-36081:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0218421470796208',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1333333'},
 'chr1:69091-70008:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:89295-90404:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.05133534609908',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7772768'},
 'chr1:137839-139228:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '9.20107516927723',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:236615-237877:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.38596464865794',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9928685'},
 'chr1:321084-321114:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '21.3658473562072',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:321146-321223:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '11.3220729579901',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:322037-322228:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.87474508698968',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9790576'},
 'chr1:323892-324060:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.84607053751675',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9702381'},
 'chr1:324288-324345:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.407845608400506',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.6842105'},
 'chr1:324439-328580:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '9.23471951459437',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9801980'},
 'chr1:367659-368595:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0252455125797539',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1463675'},
 'chr1:420206-420296:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:420992-421258:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:421396-421839:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0767494'},
 'chr1:566462-568045:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5202.77588235356',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:568149-568842:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '869.021829435309',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:568844-568912:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '30.6258557341907',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:569327-570349:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3388.6912187813',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9608610'},
 'chr1:621098-622034:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0252455125797539',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1452992'},
 'chr1:661140-665184:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '9.40353839848327',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9985163'},
 'chr1:665278-665335:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.75819876467258',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:665563-665731:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.8927274315744',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:667397-667587:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.29341136103291',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:668402-668479:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '12.9395119519887',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:668511-668541:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '24.6724665899059',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:668687-668744:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '8.83665484867764',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:670803-670994:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5.05133779571044',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9947644'},
 'chr1:671808-671885:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '8.18828490711786',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:671917-671947:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '13.4808322604641',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:674240-674404:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '6.40358801714896',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:675183-675415:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '7.4789198976791',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:675509-675566:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.94250754787156',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:678666-678730:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.88185358559662',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9375000'},
 'chr1:679575-679736:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.99559024028067',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8322982'},
 'chr1:700237-700627:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.867149997741571',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9025641'},
 'chr1:701709-701767:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.60373188387996',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9655172'},
 'chr1:703928-703993:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5.61508650757465',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9076923'},
 'chr1:704877-705092:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.3728054686264',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8465116'},
 'chr1:708356-708487:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.79204888539616',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7557252'},
 'chr1:709551-709660:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.1575534141191',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7706422'},
 'chr1:713664-714006:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.873558523726644',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7339181'},
 'chr1:761587-762902:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.17436395042983',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9749050'},
 'chr1:763064-763155:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.45701365899601',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:764383-764484:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.24181801741716',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:783034-783186:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.59761743769959',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:787307-787490:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.08544068963861',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:788051-788146:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.5174565652695',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:788771-789740:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.65784912356785',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:791898-794579:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.711474143612914',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9492726'},
 'chr1:803453-804055:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.22917316583724',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9269103'},
 'chr1:809492-810535:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0302107858074449',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1639501'},
 'chr1:812126-812182:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8214286'},
 'chr1:846815-846853:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:847325-850328:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0262483858047374',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0799201'},
 'chr1:852953-853100:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.2253739675817',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:853402-853555:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.921625141060885',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:854205-854295:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.03978221042766',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:854715-854817:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.382767723094326',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:860530-860569:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.394250754787156',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7948718'},
 'chr1:861121-861180:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1864407'},
 'chr1:861302-861393:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.599946800763064',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:865535-865716:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.51634905687368',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:866419-866469:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.00990580871884',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:871152-871276:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.82932350221241',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:874420-874509:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.7159496440893',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:874655-874840:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.22938407406748',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:876524-876686:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.35448112074115',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:877516-877631:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.12681633107055',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:877790-877868:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.39544762402323',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:877939-878438:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.90817365316984',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:878633-878757:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5.61413074816911',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:879078-879188:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5.18564055846169',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:879288-879961:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '16.7527323695907',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:879584-880180:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '27.6569876222548',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:880422-880526:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '47.4602813381872',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:880898-881033:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '41.6862195135243',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:881553-881666:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '36.2434027207842',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:881782-881925:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '27.378524637997',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:883511-883612:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '27.7521609742332',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:883870-883983:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '30.9867259902888',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:886507-886618:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '27.104739391617',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:887380-887519:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '20.6136823217285',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:887792-887980:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '17.3136574853619',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:888555-888668:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '17.222532972281',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:889162-889272:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '16.5514280838572',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:889384-889903:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.88185358559662',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9672447'},
 'chr1:891303-891393:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '16.549866849307',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:891475-891595:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '19.2237971342498',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:892274-892405:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '16.1284399685655',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:892479-894461:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.43349936389047',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7462159'},
 'chr1:894595-894679:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '8.16330974618112',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:895967-896180:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.294766919467033',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.6291080'},
 'chr1:896673-897130:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.54945711488402',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9431072'},
 'chr1:897206-897858:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.25803648224191',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9662577'},
 'chr1:898084-898297:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.09505265440384',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:898412-899229:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.9471553170417',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8470012'},
 'chr1:899300-899388:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '6.29029294154789',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:899487-899560:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '5.96703845083264',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:899729-899910:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.15912884171066',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:900343-901095:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.86397154094185',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:901877-901994:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.47008756022329',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:902084-902183:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.28665437776551',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:905657-905803:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.5019076372844',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:905901-905981:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.36284211531363',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:906066-906386:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.08081203804579',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:906457-906588:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.1504586624754',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:906704-906784:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.33630076910907',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:907455-907530:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.28250436982038',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:907668-907804:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.58996846210541',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:908241-908390:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.36550452872294',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:908566-908706:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.23688371510443',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:908880-909020:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.90135115783877',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:909213-909431:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.37630591926505',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:909696-909744:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.54021085931324',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:909822-910482:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.57461723545854',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:910579-911649:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.44300929856737',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9607477'},
 'chr1:911879-912021:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.165419897113492',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.8380282'},
 'chr1:914261-916037:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0665589344041344',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7162162'},
 'chr1:916517-916553:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.213108516101166',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:917445-917473:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.271897072267004',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7500000'},
 'chr1:934342-934812:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.31025920002665',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:934906-934993:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '13.3507641962014',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:935072-935552:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.08187700207839',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:948847-948956:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '29.3179197650813',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9449542'},
 'chr1:949364-949915:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '35.9682391505094',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:955503-955753:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '7.69652867911182',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7760000'},
 'chr1:957581-957842:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '36.2650503449254',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:970657-970704:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '39.2608043308876',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:976045-976260:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '17.3762369702487',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:976553-976777:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '10.5834424840641',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:976858-977082:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '30.6989921060932',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:977336-977542:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '40.9868417537179',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:978619-978837:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '42.017409208823',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:978918-979112:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '44.0752125864616',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:979203-979403:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '46.3685962346685',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:979489-979637:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '57.735244761448',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:979714-979819:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '55.4926534096639',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:980541-980657:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '54.1842062989528',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:980739-980903:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '53.0446470077265',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:981113-981256:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '67.2964135601965',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:981344-981468:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '62.3231593167537',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:981540-981645:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '62.2618644824245',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:981777-982115:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '43.7746265787273',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:982200-982337:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '55.5950702040439',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:982707-982834:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '65.8521963855422',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:982953-983067:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '75.4218835244995',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:983156-983275:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '70.3080512703762',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:983392-983745:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '52.7895078443819',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:984247-984439:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '83.3033460115038',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:984616-984831:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '93.6710589614669',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:984946-985175:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '96.8485549803232',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:985283-985417:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '95.145848821967',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:985613-985709:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '122.502244837989',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:985807-985971:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '98.7777345630366',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:986106-986217:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '110.81262286339',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:986633-986749:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '124.205836080808',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:986833-987025:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '123.545521500141',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:987108-987195:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '254.022929504906',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:989133-989357:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '173.925910756325',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:989828-989931:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '171.044173615351',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:990204-991492:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '141.294087417746',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:995083-995162:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.394250754787156',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7088608'},
 'chr1:995117-995226:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.43009173249508',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9449542'},
 'chr1:995657-995773:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.07829266266573',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:995660-995773:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.10666878536746',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:995919-996088:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.324677092177658',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:996400-996497:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.402296688558323',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:997229-997436:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.18954363210921',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.6231884'},
 'chr1:998459-998581:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.512846510292236',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9754099'},
 'chr1:1001210-1001833:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '2.09761619534192',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1017198-1018367:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.25251668838796',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9982891'},
 'chr1:1019295-1019763:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '1.56355310000876',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1019861-1019886:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '6.97520566161892',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1021258-1021392:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '4.26374890362406',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1022519-1022584:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '6.33190606173312',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1022878-1022977:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.94250754787156',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.9696970'},
 'chr1:1025733-1025808:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '3.00875576021777',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1026256-1026363:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.730093990346586',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.4485981'},
 'chr1:1026658-1026754:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.812888154200322',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.7187500'},
 'chr1:1026852-1027554:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.572028122166287',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.4088319'},
 'chr1:1041336-1041507:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0458431110217624',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.2807018'},
 'chr1:1050402-1050455:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1051440-1051736:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1621622'},
 'chr1:1072397-1072490:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1076205-1076412:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0096618'},
 'chr1:1078119-1079432:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0180023175701898',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1827875'},
 'chr1:1102484-1102578:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.5106383'},
 'chr1:1103243-1103332:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1104385-1104467:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.190000363752846',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1109286-1109306:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1109646-1109701:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1109804-1109869:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1108436-1111776:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.00944030541244313',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1114569-1114713:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1114745-1114935:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1115037-1115233:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1115414-1115720:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1115863-1115981:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1116111-1116240:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1117121-1117195:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1117741-1117826:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1118256-1118427:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.0000000'},
 'chr1:1119300-1119471:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.183372444087049',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.3274854'},
 'chr1:1120349-1121241:+': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '0.0176596082771403',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '0.1076233'},
 'chr1:1229203-1229313:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '13.5679088584409',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1229470-1229579:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': '13.1894797965158',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': '1.0000000'},
 'chr1:1229782-1230008:-': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': nan, 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': nan}})
```

`clin_kipan.head().to_dict()`

```
pd.DataFrame({'admin.disease_code': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 'kirp'},
 'days_to_death': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 1771.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': nan},
 'vital_status': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 'alive',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 'alive',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 'alive',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 'dead',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 'alive'},
 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 53.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 71.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 71.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 67.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 80.0},
 'gender': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 'male',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 'male',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 'female',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 'male',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 'male'},
 'karnofsky_performance_score': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': nan},
 'patient.gender': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 1,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 0},
 'patient.vital_status': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 1,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 0},
 'survival': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01': 'lts'}})
```

Comment: show us your desired output as well and explain it in plain english

Comment: Hi, when I run your code with the dataframes you provided, it does not raise any error.